# How can I launch a DialogFragment from clicking a preference item?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-dialogfragment

In my preferences.xml file I have things like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title = "Random Title"
        android:key = "random_category">

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And I have a PreferenceFragment:

```
public class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```

I want to add an item to the category where if you click on it, it calls SomeFunc() (which launches a DialogFragment and from there I know how to save preference values using a helper I wrote), but I don't know how to include just a regular clickable Preference that triggers this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add on click event

```
    Preference button = findPreference(preferenceKey);
    button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            // Do some stuff here
            return true;
        }
    });
```

It is also worth checking out Android Studio's default preference page (New -> Activity -> Settings Activity) - it's quite neet but not too straightforward.

Comment: beat me to the punch...+1

Comment: I tried using the default preference page but I had no idea what I was supposed to actually do with it.

Comment: Oh I know, it is a bit overwhelming example, but it showcases important design and functionality features, it just takes time to get your head around it.